# Cooling by voiding an isolated chamber

Tags: thermodynamics

If we take the law of an ideal gas:

```
pV = nRT
```

We see that reducing the pressure to 0, or close to it, would lead to a similar drop in the temperature.

What would be the temperature inside of a voided (emptied of any gas) chamber?
Could we use it as a cooling storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a vacuum chamber, the temperature of solid contents would equilibrate with the temperature of the chamber walls, regardless of the temperature of the gas. In a near-vacuum, radiation will dominate heat exchange.

The temperature of the gas remaining in the chamber would indeed be very low until it was heated by contact with the contents and walls. However, there would not be enough gas to affect the temperature of the other contents. The heat capacity of a material varies directly with its mass, so if there is very little mass of air in the chamber, it takes very little energy to increase its temperature to thermal equilibrium with its surroundings.

Answer (score 1):

If the chamber walls were perfect insulation and we pumped the gas out of the chamber (say, through a valve), the gas remaining within the chamber at any time will have done work on the gas expelled through the valve ahead of it to force the expelled gas out.  By the 1st law of thermodynamics, this will have caused the gas still remaining within the chamber to cool down.  We can calculate how much cooling has occurred by analyzing this adiabatic (nearly reversible) expansion.